# How to remove pattern lock In Samsung Phone without data loss?

Tags: applications, samsung, security, locked-out, pattern-lock

I have a Samsung Galaxy M12 which I forgot the Pattern lock of it and This has some very important data in it. So, Now I have been running around Internet for the probable solution but nothing worked like the Google Find my device also didn't work, The phone also does not have usb debugging enabled and No Backup as well. I remember it was android 10 or 11 when I last updated. The phone also get locked for 24 hours after trying wrong pattern for the maximum attempts and the phone isn't rooted.
Also I have forgotten the Samsung's account password. So, is there any possible way other than resetting the phone itself and throwing it away, as I don't want the pain of the data. I tried to use adb but realized there was no usb debugging enabled.

Comment: Was the phone rebooted since the last successful pattern lock entry? If yes your user data is encrypted and can only be decrypted/accessed by entering the correct pattern.

Comment: Nope it wasn't rebooted Samsung does not let you reboot but only power off. Because of the wrong attempts attempted.

Comment: Power off is the same as reboot in this situation - the decryption key is no longer available in RAM and thus you need to enter the correct pattern to get it back. No key means no data access.

Comment: Any adb or settings manipulation haven't tried any softwares because I was bit hesitant it will remove the data there must be a way. Please??

Comment: If there was a way, it wouldn't be secure and it would be pointless to have pins and passwords.  If you have really forgotten your Samsung password, talk to Samsung support.

Comment: So if not that is there away to backup the data of this locked phone ?. Like I know how to get the google drive ones but I now here want the physically stored data on this phone.